# Is it possible to restrict Here API access to specific ip addresses?

Tags: here-api

The idea behind would be to prevent someone else to make bogus requests to Here API on my behalf, without necessarily having to resort to SSL.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bind it. (Last sentence) from https://developer.here.com/faqs :

> ***How do you control access to the HERE Platform? Do I need to take any special precautions?***
>
> HERE APIs use two random strings, app_id and app_code, to provide
>   secure access to their services.
>
> HERE APIs use a combination of app_id and app_code to uniquely
>   identify a user, an application, and to track usage for an
>   application.
>
> app_id uniquely identifies your application. app_code is used in the
>   authentication process to identify a session.
>
> Please note that the app_ids and app_codes generated for Evaluation
>   licenses will expire 90 days after they are issued.
>
> For additional protection, you can associate specific domains,
>   referrers or hostnames to an app id from the Applications page.

The page to configure this is: https://developer.here.com/applications

Comment: Thanks for making me realise I'm blind!